# How to Manage Tabs in Tabbedpage from ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing application, where I have to dynamicaly create/delete tabs in TabbedPage.

Let say that I have workout with excercises, each excercise has to have own page. When I'm passing workoutViewModel by contructor I can create tabs in code behind, rest code I have in viewModel. User can add or remove some excercise this cause that tabs have to change.

How can I manage tabs in tabbedPage from ViewModel? This ViewModel is BindingContext in this page.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I manage tabs in tabbedPage from ViewModel? This ViewModel is BindingContext in this page.

If you want to display tab in Tabbedpage with ViewModel, I think you can assign a DataTemplate to the ItemTemplate property to return pages for objects in the collection.

Like this sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TabbedPage